# Use pie graph to answer question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

What percent o people preferred either pop or classical?

Country 20%
Jazz 21%
Pop 12%
Classical 13%
Rock 14%
Rap 11%

Comment: welcome Lisa hint: use $p(A\cup B)=p(A)+p(B)-p(A\cap B)$

Answer (score 2):

Data is insufficient unless these sets are assumed disjoint.

If sets are disjoint, then People who prefer either pop or classical=People who preferpop+People who prefer classical